# Find max, min of 2D-function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have obtained a result, but I'm not sure that it agrees with WolframAlpha results. Can you help me to understand?

$$f(x,y)=e^{(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)}$$

The function is always increasing, so I can look for max and min of $$g(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

Looking for critical points: 
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{4xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\frac{-4x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=0$$

So critical points are in the form: $(0,k), (k,0)$

$\Delta f(0,k)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}+1=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ It's always $>0$ so $(0,k)$ are minima.

$\Delta f(k,0)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-1=\frac{-2y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ It's always $<0$ so $(k,0)$ are maxima.

But WolframAlpha says: 
Global max: (-1,0) (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+of+%7B%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%7D)

Global min: (0,-1) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+of+%7B%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%7D

Is it correct my sentence:  "$(0,k)$ are local minima; $(k,0)$ are local maxima"?

How can I obtain the WolframAlpha results? Many thanks!

Comment: i am wondering if using polar coordinates won't make it easier? you need to find the extremum of $e^{\cos 2 \theta}$

Comment: Your analysis is correct, Wolfram Alpha seems to have a weak definition of global maximum: $$\max_{x,y} f(x,y) \geq f(x_{0},y_{0}),\qquad \forall x_{0},y_{0}$$ Rather than a strict definition, which might be: $$\max_{x,y}f(x,y) > f(x_{0},y_{0}),\qquad\forall (x_{0},y_{0})\neq (x_{\text{max}},y_{\text{max}})$$

Comment: @abel yes, you are right! But there's a step that I can't understand. In polar coordinates, I have critical point for $\theta=0$ (max) and $\theta=\pi/2$(min). Let's consider $\theta=0$: since $\theta=arctan (y/x)$ -> $y/x=0$, so y=0 and x=k, so (k,0) are max. And this is OK, I have obtained tha same result using cartesian coord. But let's consider $\theta=\pi/2$, $y/x=tg (\pi/2)$ that is infinity. So, I should conclude that minima don't exist. But this don't agree with result in cartesian coordinates and WolframAlpha result.. I don't understand what's wrong...... :/

Comment: @Shaktal Thanks for your answer! but in which way can I obtain the results (-1,0) and (0,-1) that WolframAlpha shows me? Thanks again...

Comment: @sunrise you can just choose any $k$ in your result for your result to be a valid Wolfram|Alpha result, my guess is they randomly select a result somehow

Comment: @Shaktal a lot of thanks!